# Aliases for field names in kibana

Tags: kibana

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1896 
I found some pages for aliases for field names in kibana. 
After enabling a feature of 'shortDots:enable', I don't know how to configure in the visualization or discover. 
Can anyone elaborate how to set up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`shortDots:enable` just shorten a long field name `a.long.field.name` to `a.l.f.name`.If you want to set an independent alias to this field, it's impossible until kibana v5.1.0 ( according to official kibana's roadmap ).

You can go to `Settings > Advanced` and click on the right side of `shortDots:enable` item and check.